# worker disconnecting with ZK for long running bolt

Tags: apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I have a bolt which uses a pool of large objects. When pool reinitialises(once in 4 hours) bolt waits for few seconds and disconnects with zookeper.
I have specified following properties in yaml but still worker dies.

```
supervisor.worker.start.timeout.secs 300
supervisor.worker.timeout.secs 60
```

Here are the logs:

```
2015-02-17 04:35:01 o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 15906ms for sessionid 0x14b9200ea400009, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2015-02-17 04:35:01 o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager [INFO] State change: SUSPENDED
2015-02-17 04:35:01 o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager [WARN] There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
2015-02-17 04:35:01 b.s.cluster [WARN] Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Zookeeper.
2015-02-17 04:35:02 o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server realtimeanalytics.novalocal/10.0.0.11:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (Unable to locate a login configuration)
2015-02-17 04:35:02 o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Socket connection established to realtimeanalytics.novalocal/10.0.0.11:2181, initiating session
2015-02-17 04:35:02 o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Session establishment complete on server realtimeanalytics.novalocal/10.0.0.11:2181, sessionid = 0x14b9200ea400009, negotiated timeout = 20000
2015-02-17 04:35:02 o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager [INFO] State change: RECONNECTED
2015-02-17 04:35:02 o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager [WARN] There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
2015-02-17 04:35:33 o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 13499ms for sessionid 0x14b9200ea400009, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2015-02-17 04:35:34 o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager [INFO] State change: SUSPENDED
2015-02-17 04:35:34 b.s.cluster [WARN] Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Zookeeper.
2015-02-17 04:35:34 o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager [WARN] There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the worker heartbeat timeouts?

```
worker.heartbeat.frequency.secs: 60
```

Comment: zookeeper problem was solved by adding `storm.zookeeper.session.timeout: 40000
storm.zookeeper.connection.timeout: 30000`    But still worker was moved to other node might be because of memory pressure